# Bar Chart offsets with multiple plots

Tags: pgfplots, width, bar-chart

I want to create some histograms and need to represent a few bar charts. However, I am facing two issues with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines =center,
ybar=0pt, bar width=1cm,
samples at ={0,...,4},
xmin=-1,
xmax=4.6,]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {x + 1};
\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {4 - x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I only use the first plot, the sample at x = 0 doesn't plot and I don't understand why:

[image]

If I only use the second plot, the bar chart plots as intended:

[image]

And most importantly, if I plot both, I do get a sample for x = 0 for the first plot, but it is weirdly offset / the width is reduced by some factor for both:

[image]

How do I fix this width change with multiple plots and what is the reason for the width change?

What is the reason the sample at x = 0 doesn't show for the first plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `ybar` option to be the first option to setup plot type - (important for e.g. spacing).

Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar=0pt,
xmin=-1, xmax=4.6,
axis lines=center,
samples at={0,...,4},
bar width=10pt,
]
\addplot[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {x + 1};
\addplot[fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {4 - x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar plot with bars next to each other]

-or like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
xmin=-1, xmax=4.6,
axis lines=center,
samples at={0,...,4},
bar width=10pt,
bar shift=0pt,
]
\addplot[fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {x + 1};
\addplot[fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {4 - x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar plot with overlapping bars]

Edit: Regarding the missing bar - In your first picture, the bar at x=0 is not missing. The value of that bar is 1 - so right where the x-axis is. You probably want to give the option `ymin=0`.